# Grafana shows only one log level (logs) (grafana + loki-distributed helm chart)

Tags: logging, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I deployed victoria-metrics with promtail to pass logs to Loki. I installed Loki and i get all the logs. the only problem is that the log label shown as logs,and not as Info/error/warning. It is colorize them though when I look at the log itself.

the grafana explore ui:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zupU8.png)

the loki configuration:

```yaml
gateway:

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: internal-nginx
    annotations:
      external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: loki.myhostname.com


    hosts:
      - host: loki.myhostname.com
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
    tls: []

read:
  autoscaling:
    enabled: true
    minReplicas: 3
    maxReplicas: 5

write:
  autoscaling:
    enabled: true
    minReplicas: 3
    maxReplicas: 5

loki:
  structuredConfig:
    ingester:
      max_transfer_retries: 0
      chunk_idle_period: 1h
      chunk_target_size: 1536000
      max_chunk_age: 1h
    storage_config:
      aws:
        s3: s3://eu-central-1
        bucketnames: loki-centralized
      boltdb_shipper:
        shared_store: s3
    schema_config:
      configs:
        - from: "2022-08-17"
          store: boltdb-shipper
          object_store: aws
          schema: v11
          index:
            prefix: loki_index_
            period: 24h

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: loki-sa
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "my-sa-role"
```

my promtail:

```yaml
extraArgs:
- -client.external-labels=cluster=dev-03

config:
  lokiAddress: http://my-loki-host.com/loki/api/v1/push
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. turns out it is Grafana version 9.x, at least for us it didn't work. we downgrade to 8.3.x, the log labels are back to normal. now I see it as it should with the colors.